# Switching tab/window with Selenium CDP

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a Selenium application where I need to switch between and interact with multiple tabs through CDP.

I'm able to create/open all of these tabs and store their respective targetIds with no issue:

```
var targetId = session.SendCommand("Target.createTarget", JToken.Parse($"{{ url: '{url}'  }}")).Result["targetId"].ToString();
```

But when I try to switch to one of the newly created tabs with the code below, the first tab still remains active.

```
session.SendCommand("Target.activateTarget", JToken.Parse($"{{ targetId: '{targetId}' }}"))
```

If I run the Page.reload method, the first tab is reloaded rather than the one I tried to switch to. I've also tried Target.attachToTarget together with Target.activateTarget to switch tab, but that didn't work either.

What is the correct way to switch target to a specific tab/window?